# Are there any global standards to identify a movie?

Tags: film-industry, distribution

I know there exist approaches like **EIDR** (Entertainment Identifier Registry) and **ISAN** (International Standard Audiovisual Number). But I do not know how many movies are contained within those lists. Is there anything like **IBAN** just for movies?

Comment: www.imdb.com/title/tt<number> ?? (also TV series and now episodes)

Comment: "As of late 2015, [EIDR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EIDR) contains over 827K content assets (up 14% from 2014), including 143K movies, and 387K episodes of over 24K TV series." "Having a rich set of Alternate IDs for content is one of the primary goals of EIDR. This allows EIDR IDs to be used everywhere in content workflows; if an alternate ID is needed it can be found in the metadata for the EIDR ID. EIDR supports the inclusion both proprietary and other standard (e.g. ISAN) ID references." Anything non-proprietary and non-profit would be my goto, so these would be it IMO.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I turned your comment into an answer. If you want to post the answer yourself (to get the reputation), I'll delete mine.

Answer (score 2):

This answer was posted as a comment by someone else. I'm just moving it to an answer, because I think it's the best answer possible.

IMDB has a unique ID number for each movie, tv show, and episode in its database. You can see it in the URL after the "tt".

This ID is used by various media apps (e.g. Plex) to download metadata for a video.

---

For example, the movie Avengers: Infinity War has this URL:

https://www.imdb.com/title/tt4154756/.

so it's ID would be 4154756.